# dbt build command and exclude specific tests

Tags: dbt

I have some sql models that gets refreshed. After the dbt run, there are some fields that gets updated outside of dbt [ a binary needs to be run and output of the binary is used to update the fields ]. I want to classify these tests using tags as `post_binary`.
Now, my goal is to build the sql models and run all the tests other that `post_binary` during `dbt build`

models

- model1
- model2
- run tests other than `post_binary`
- run binary and output [outside of dbt]
- run tests with tags `post_binary`

-- run dv

Answer (score 0):

```
dbt run
```

do other external tasks, than:

```
dbt test --exclude tag:post_binary
```